# Images not showing in scroll view (only code, no storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[What I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njEN0.jpg)Ive searched myself around without any answers. First of all I'm not using storyboards (found very simply solutions for that with my problem)

Im using a UIscrollview and Pagecontrol to create something like this just to be as clear as possible.

when I load my app, the uiscrollview and page panel (set to black color) is showing, so its nothing wrong with the normal constrains.

However I'm not able to load my images and neither can I see the small round buttons showing which "page" I'm on.

here is the most important code concerning this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
var images: [String] = ["0.jpg", "1.jpg"]
var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

 lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scroll = UIScrollView()
    scroll.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scroll.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    return scroll

}()

lazy var pageControl: UIPageControl = {
    let page = UIPageControl()
    page.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    page.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return page
}()
```

the methods:

```
func testScroll() {
    for index in 0..<images.count {
       frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size

        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: images[index])
        self.scrollView.addSubview(imgView)


    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(images.count)), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

    scrollView.delegate = self
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
}
```

Comment: where did u add scrollview on your mainview? plz also check for imageview width & height

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. The scroll view is is in the middle of the screen, constrained to some other objects: scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonlogin.centerYAnchor, constant: -130).isActive = true
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true

Comment: do I need to put contrails for image view manuallly with constrains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be calling `testScroll()` too soon? `scrollView`'s frame would be `(0, 0, 0, 0)`. The same would apply for all its images. That might explain your page control, too.

`viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is fired once all subviews' frames are calculated. That would be a place to call `testScroll()`.

Comment: I tried that too but I think I add them in the right order. Like this:view.addSubview(buttonlogin)
        view.addSubview(welcomeLabel)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        view.addSubview(pageControl)

        handleConstrains()
  
        testScroll()

Comment: In `viewDidLoad()`? That's too soon. You need to call `testScroll()` inside `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. That's where scroll view gets a proper frame.

Comment: oh that explains it all, that worked:) thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I helped. :)